# How do I know when the Solidity SMTChecker did not find any unproven targets?

Tags: solidity, smtchecker

From the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.18/smtchecker.html#unproved-targets):

> If there are any unproved targets, the SMTChecker issues one warning stating how many unproved targets there are.

However, the docs don't say anything about the converse, i.e. what happens if the SMTChecker does not find any unproven targets.

Is it that when the build passes successfully and no warnings are printed, that means the SMTChecker proved the contract successfully (i.e. it did not find any unproven targets)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, that's the behavior currently which I agree can be confusing. We'll soon add successful properties to the report too.

Comment: Looks like your [recent PR 13957](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/13957) has addressed this issue? If yes, will this be included in Solidity v0.8.20?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It's already available in the nightlies if you wanna play with it, and it'll be part of the next release.

Comment: Good stuff, thanks for confirming.